# Vue.js v-for with extra li doesn't render

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a ul with items coming from the loop, and then extra li after that.

```
<ul>
  <todo-item v-for="(todo,index) in todos" v-bind:todo="todo" :key="index" />
  <li :key='"new_item"'>
    <input placeholder="What needs to be done?" type="text" v-model="new_todo" >
    <button v-on:click="add_todo()">Add</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This doesn't show the extra line. But if I switch it so extra li is first it does.

```
<ul>
  <li :key='"new_item"'>
    <input placeholder="What needs to be done?" type="text" v-model="new_todo" >
    <button v-on:click="add_todo()">Add</button>
  </li>
  <todo-item v-for="(todo,index) in todos" v-bind:todo="todo" :key="index" />
</ul>
```

So I'm probably doing something wrong with key, but I can't find what exactly.

[The whole code is here](https://codepen.io/taw/pen/eKyzKe).

Comment: change to `<todo-item v-for="(todo,index) in todos" v-bind:todo="todo" :key="index"></todo-item>` then try again. check [Vue self-closing tag](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1036)

Comment: The self-closing tag rule everyone is mentioning is true, but confusing as well, because it *only* applies if your template is an "in DOM" template, meaning, your template is rendered at some point in the DOM. If you use a string template, or a single file component, the issue does not apply. [Here is an example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/bKaBNK) of your code working *as is* in a string template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that vue components require a closing tag and won't work properly just with self-closing tags.

Try like that:

```
<ul>
  <todo-item v-for="(todo,index) in todos" v-bind:todo="todo" :key="index"></todo-item>
  <li :key='"new_item"'>
    <input placeholder="What needs to be done?" type="text" v-model="new_todo" >
    <button v-on:click="add_todo()">Add</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

From the official [Vue Style Guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Self-closing-components-strongly-recommended):

> Components that self-close communicate that they not only have no
> content, but are meant to have no content. It’s the difference between
> a blank page in a book and one labeled “This page intentionally left
> blank.” Your code is also cleaner without the unnecessary closing tag.
>
> Unfortunately, HTML doesn’t allow custom elements to be self-closing -
> only official “void” elements. That’s why the strategy is only
> possible when Vue’s template compiler can reach the template before
> the DOM, then serve the DOM spec-compliant HTML.

Comment: For future reference, this only applies to in DOM templates.

Answer (score 2):

You are not allowed to use self-closing tags, so instead of `<todo-item />` use `<todo-item></todo-item>`

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1036

Not a valid HTML5 components it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use SFC or usual HTML files?
Maybe the problem is that HTML parser doesn't allow to use `<todo-item>` inside `<ul>`. Try to use `<li :is="'todo-item'" v-for...>` instead (it's works in your codepen)

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>TODOs</h1>
  <ul>
    <li :is="'todo-item'" v-for="(todo,index) in todos" v-bind:todo="todo" :key="index"></li>
    <li :key='"new_item"'>
      <input placeholder="What needs to be done?" type="text" v-model="new_todo" >
      <button v-on:click="add_todo()">Add</button>
    </li>
  </ul>  
  <p>You have finished {{ done }}/{{ total }}</p>
</div>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats

Comment: This was one of my first thoughts, and it definitely applies to tables, [but does not appear to be an issue](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/NzXRZz?editors=1010) with `ul`, at least in my version of chrome. I agree that the documentation states `ul` *should* be affected, which seems a bit misleading.